# SwiftUI: Change only one instance of UITableViewAppearance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swiftui

I know that the component `List` has an `UITableView` behind. I also know I can change the background by changing the `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor`.

What I want is to change this for a single `View` that has a `List` component, without affecting the rest of the application. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I know needs to be done to achieve this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    List {
        //Your content
    }
    .onAppear {
        //The specific table view settings.
        //UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = .black
    }
    .onDisappear {
        //The general table view settings
        //UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = nil
    }
}
```

But it is problematic for several reasons.

The biggest reason is the fact you might have 2 table views in the same View and you want them to have different appearances.

The second issue is that not all cases will call onAppear (I don't remember specific cases but I remember having issues with TabViews)

I hope there's already a better solution waiting in the next version of SwiftUI.